# ¿Cómo mostrar una respuesta de Ajax en cada elemento de un foreach en laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, ajax, foreach

tengo un foreach en la vista de laravel que muestra todos los productos, pero necesito mostrar el precio para cada producto a través de ajax, para esto hago la consulta y ajax me retorna el precio, y quiero asignar dicho precio a cada producto del foreach. Pero el precio solo se muestra en el primer producto. Lo que quiero es que mientras se van mostrando los productos con foreach, ajax vaya consultando la tarifa y la muestre en ese primer producto, y así con todos los productos. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

**Esta es la vista:**

```
<div class="row">
            @foreach ($products as $product)
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 mt-4 pt-2">
                    {!!Form::open(['route' => ['detail', $product->slug]])!!}
                        <div class="card blog rounded border-0 shadow overflow-hidden">
                            <div class="position-relative">
                                <img src="{{$product->file}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{$product->name}}">
                                <div class="overlay bg-dark"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="position-relative">
                                <div class="shape overflow-hidden text-white">
                                    <svg viewBox="0 0 2880 48" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                        <path d="M0 48H1437.5H2880V0H2160C1442.5 52 720 0 720 0H0V48Z" fill="currentColor"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body content">
                                <h5><span class="h5" id="nota"></span></h5>
                                <small><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-primary h6">Destino: {{$request->destination}}</a></small>
                                {{Form::hidden('destination', $request->destination)}}
                                {{Form::hidden('pax', $request->pax)}}
                                {{Form::hidden('date', $request->date)}}
                                {{Form::hidden('start_date', $request->start_date)}}
                                {{Form::hidden('end_date', $request->end_date)}}
                                {{Form::hidden('reservation_price')}}
                                <h5 class="mt-2"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="title text-dark">{{$product->name}}</a></h5>
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <h5><span class="h5">{{$request->pax}} pasajero(s) COP </span><span id="precio_total"></span></h5>
                                </div>
                                <p class="text-muted">{!!$product->summary_includes!!}</p>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" class="text-primary">Ver detalle de cobertura <i data-feather="chevron-right" class="fea icon-sm"></i></a>
                                <ul class="list-unstyled d-flex justify-content-between border-top mt-3 pt-3 mb-0">
                                    <li class="text-muted small ml-3"><i data-feather="clock" class="fea icon-sm text-warning"></i> {{$request->days}} día(s) de asistencia</li>
                                    {{Form::submit('Comprar', ['class' => 'text-white h6 btn btn-primary float-right'])}}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!--end card / course-blog-->
                    {!!Form::close()!!}
                </div>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Cobertura asistencia {{$product->name}}</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        {!!$product->includes!!}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div><!--end row-->
```

**Este es el ajax:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var cantidad_dias = {{$request->days}};
        var age = [{{implode(",",$request->age)}}];
        var ids = {{$ids}};
        var total = 0;
        for(var x = 0; x < ids.length; x++){
            var url = "{{route('tarifa', ['id' => 'temp'])}}";
            url = url.replace('temp', ids[x]);
            for(var i = 0; i < age.length; i++){
                $.ajax({
                    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                    type:"GET",
                    url:url,
                    data:{cantidad_dias:cantidad_dias,age:age[i]},
                    datatype:"json",
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response.id);
                        total = total+response.total;
                        $("#precio_total").html('$' + new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(total));
                        $("input[name=reservation_price]").val(total);
                    },
                    error:function(){
                        $("#nota").html("Algo salio mal, por favor inténtalo de nuevo.");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: estas sobre cargando el ajax, no hagas una consuta por cada producto, mejor devuelve el rango de productos en una sola consulta por ajax.

Comment: Hola John, gracias por responder, me puede dar un ejemplo por favor. Muchas gracias.

Comment: ahora el que solo te muestra uno es por que todas las llamadas las mandas al mismo objeto $("#precio_total"),  $("input[name=reservation_price]"). debes poner un id que lo pueda identificar para colocar el precio en el span indicado. estas usando el mismo id para varios tag html eso causa problemas.

Comment: recuerda blade se ejecuta en el server y ajax en el navegador del cliente

Comment: no entiendo por que usas productos en BLADE y usas días en  ej JS

Comment: Bueno, lo que pasa es que tengo un buscador en el index, el usuario ingresa los datos necesarios para realizar la consulta, entre ellos la cantidad de días, con esta información filtro los productos a mostrar. Por otro lado, las tarifas las tengo en otra tabla, y estas tarifas están asociadas con el id de cada producto. Seguro hay una forma más simple de hacerlo, pero estoy en proceso de aprendizaje. Quiero consultar sobre su respuesta "debes poner un id que lo pueda identificar para colocar el precio en el span indicado", pensé que era lo que estaba haciendo, esta mal?. Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: coloca un id diferente para cada tag html que muestre el precio, usa el id del producto para cuando devuelvas el valor tambien taigas el id y lo asignes al tag correcto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esta es la forma de hacer lo que quieres, lo deje simple para que entiendas

cada div tiene un id unico

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<div id="prod_{{$product->id}}">
</div>
@endforeach
```

este es el ejemplo JS

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var cantidad_dias = {{$request->days}};
                var age = [{{implode(",",$request->age)}}];
                var ids = {{$ids}};
                var total = 0;
                for(var x = 0; x < ids.length; x++){
                    var url = "{{route('tarifa', ['id' => 'temp'])}}";
                    url = url.replace('temp', ids[x]);
                    for(var i = 0; i < age.length; i++){
                        $.ajax({
                            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                            type:"GET",
                            url:url,
                            data:{cantidad_dias:cantidad_dias,age:age[i]},
                            datatype:"json",
                            success: function(response){
                            // armas el ID y mandas al div la info deseada
                                $("#prod_"+response.idprod).html('$' + new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(total));
                            },
                            error:function(){
                                $("#nota").html("Algo salio mal, por favor inténtalo de nuevo.");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Hola John, sus indicaciones me ayudaron a dar solución a mi consulta. Voy a seguir sus recomendaciones. Muchas gracias.